# Determine the best design pattern for This system

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, uml, software-design

I want to design a Lights hardware controller that do the following:

1. Have commands that control the lights for  the place like turn on, turn off, turn on all lights, turn off all lights.
2. Other operation may be defined in the future such as adding affects or like these operation(which pattern tat help me to add new operation to existing one without polluting the existing system).
3. The controller should support multiple kinds of lights(is adapter a good option here?? any other options??) .
4. The controller have a computer UI in addition to manual control(which is the best pattern for providing interface between the controller and the software UI).

I want to use some design patterns here like (Iterator, Composite, Observer, Facade, Factory, Builder, Template Method, Decorator, Command, Visitor, Proxy, and/or Adapter). I want to know which patterns are best suitable for each and how I can apply them here? And if there if is any example similar to this one?

Comment: Can you add more details of exactly what operations are required?  Also, your question is a pretty big ask, so can you state what you've tried?

Comment: I rephrased the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Is this an exercise in which you hope to include as many patterns as possible? If not, remember that a pattern is not an end in itself. It should help you solve a common problem in a well-proven way.

Answer (score 0):

All this

> providing interface between the controller and the software UI

reminds me about the [Mediator design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern). Since it defines simplified communication between classes. Also define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently.

About the

> multiple kinds of lights

I think that concept of [divergent change](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/divergent-change) will help you greatly. In short through the rest of your list:

1. [Command design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern) - encapsulate your commands as an object
2. [Builder](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern) with [Decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) or [State](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern)
3. [Facade](http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern) for the *Controller* and [Composite](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) for the *lights*